# Steam Trade Offer Link — Параметры ссылки

Tags: steam-web-api

Вывел содержимое инвентаря *STEAM* (купоны и карточки) на сайте, и для удобства обмена решил добавить *Trade Offer Link* для каждого предмета. Для карточек (*AppID 753/6*) это не составило проблем и ссылка имеет такой вид:
`https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?for_tradingcard=218640_2&partner=123456789&token=123456`.

При клике на нее открывается окно обмена и уже автоматом вставляется нужная карточка (не нужно искать).

Столкнулся с проблемой формирования такой ссылки для категории Купоны (*AppID 753/3*). Поиск по этому вопросу совсем не дал информации. Делал попытки сделать разными способами:

```
for_coupon=classid купона  
for_item=classid купона
```

Данные о купонах можно получить в ввиде *JSON* сделав запрос:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/id/CUSTOMURL/inventory/json/753/3?l=russian
```

Как сформировать такую ссылку для купонов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобный GET параметр доступен только для коллекционных карточек.
В качестве альтернативы можно воспользоваться плагином для браузера, который сам подставляет предметы. Но раз это плагин, то не факт, что он стоит у всех

http://forums.backpack.tf/index.php?/topic/17946-script-steam-trade-offer-enhancer/

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Я знаком с этим userscript. Жаль, что подобные запросы не предусмотрены в API STEAM для всех предметов.